# Random sampling only a subset of data in R

Tags: r, resampling

I have a dataset (N of 2794) of which I want to extract a subset, randomly reallocate the class and put it back into the dataframe.

Example

```
| Index | B | C | Class|
| 1     | 3 | 4 | Dog  |
| 2     | 1 | 9 | Cat  |
| 3     | 9 | 1 | Dog  |
| 4     | 1 | 1 | Cat  |
```

From the above example, I want to random take N number of observations from column 'Class' and mix them up so you get something like this..

```
| Index | B | C | Class|
| 1     | 3 | 4 | Cat  | Re-sampled 
| 2     | 1 | 9 | Dog  | Re-sampled 
| 3     | 9 | 1 | Dog  |
| 4     | 1 | 1 | Dog  | Re-sampled
```

This code randomly *extracts* rows and re samples them, but I don't want to extract the rows. I want to keep them in the dataframe.

```
 sample(Class[sample(nrow(Class),N),])
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose `df` is your data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(index=1:4, B=c(3,1,9,1), C=c(4,9,1,1), Class=c("Dog", "Cat", "Dog", "Cat"))
```

Would this do what you want?

```
dfSamp <- sample(1:nrow(df), N)
df$Class[dfSamp] <- sample(df$Class[dfSamp])
```

Answer (score 1):

I simulated the data frame and did an example:

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID=1:4,
  Class=c('Dog', 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Cat')
)

N <- 2
sample_ids <- sample(nrow(df), N)

df$Class[sample_ids] <- sample(df$Class, length(sample_ids))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Class` is how you named your datafame, you could do this:

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(
  Class %>% 
    mutate(origin = 'not_sampled'),
  Class %>% 
    sample(100, replace = TRUE) %>% 
    mutate(origin = 'sampled'))
```

Sample 100 observations of the original dataframe and stack them to the bottom of it. I am also adding a column so that you know if the observation was sampled or present in the dataframe from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

What you're wanting to do is replace in-line some classes, but not others.

So, if we start with a data frame, `df`

```
set.seed(100)
df = data.frame(index = 1:100,
                B = sample(1:10,100,replace = T),
                C = sample(1:10,100,replace = T),
                Class = sample(c('Cat','Dog','Bunny'),100,replace = T))
```

And you want to update 5 random rows, then we need to pick which rows to update and what new classes to put in those rows. By referencing `unique(df$class)` you don't weight the classes by their current occurrence. You could adjust this with the `weight` argument or remove `unique` to use occurrence as weight.

```
n_rows = 5
rows_to_update = sample(1:100,n_rows,replace = F)
new_classes = sample(unique(df$Class),n_rows,replace = T)
rows_to_update
#> [1] 85 65 94 60 48
new_classes
#> [1] "Bunny" "Dog"   "Dog"   "Dog"   "Bunny"
```

We can inspect what the original data looked like

```
df[rows_to_update,]
#>    index B  C Class
#> 85    85 1  2   Dog
#> 65    65 5  1 Bunny
#> 94    94 5 10   Dog
#> 60    60 3  7 Bunny
#> 48    48 9  1   Cat
```

We can update this in place with a reference to the column and the rows to update.

```
df$Class[rows_to_update] = new_classes
df[rows_to_update,]
#>    index B  C Class
#> 85    85 1  2 Bunny
#> 65    65 5  1   Dog
#> 94    94 5 10   Dog
#> 60    60 3  7   Dog
#> 48    48 9  1 Bunny
```

Comment: Thanks! Does that mean if you remove the unique from the df$Class you _are_ taking account of the class weights?

Comment: Right, if `df$Class` was Dog: 10, Cat: 20, Bunny 5 then without `unique` you'd expect Cat to be selected twice a often as Dog and Dog to be selected twice as often as Bunny.